# Why is . in the path by default?

Tags: linux, security, path

Many says for security reasons the current directory is not in the `$PATH` variable and Linux does not look in the current directory to see whether a specific command is available from that directory. but I did `cd /usr/bin` then do `ls` and it worked just fine; also I did `echo $PATH` and the output contains `/usr/bin`.

> You should notice that for security reasons the current directory is
>   not in the `$PATH`variable and Linux does not look in the current
>   directory to see whether a specific command is available from that
>   directory.
>
> Red Hat® RHCSATM/RHCE® 7 Cert Guide by Sander van Vugt

Why am I able to run `ls` while being in `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> linux does not look in the current directory to see whether a specific command is available from that directory

That's true, but it *does* look in all directories mentioned in `$PATH`, even though you might be in such a directory at that moment.

To word it in another way, if `.` is not in your `$PATH`, it *doesn't matter* where you are, it will always search the same directories to see whether a specific command is available there.

Comment: But as I understood the current directory should not be in $PATH why its still in $PATH after I changed to /usr/bin directory?

"You should notice that for security reasons the current directory is not in the $PATH variable and Linux does not look in the current directory to see whether
a specific command is available from that directory. " Red Hat® RHCSATM/RHCE® 7 Cert Guide by Sander van Vugt

Comment: That just means it *normally* doesn't look in the current directory (contrary to Windows, which does).

Comment: So linux doesn't look in current directory unless its in $PATH, am I right?

Comment: Yes, and if `.` is in `$PATH` it will *always* look in the current directory.

Comment: I am not a root user, still `.` is not present in the PATH variable in my case(CentOS7)

Answer (score 1):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1373279/432690) is good but the discussion in comments indicates a broader explanation may be useful.

[This document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01) describes in what sequence a POSIX-compliant shell should search for commands. It's very generic, not the easiest thing to understand. Instead of analyzing this highly abstract procedure, let's see how a real shell acts.

Assuming

- your `$PATH` looks like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`;
- you're in Bash;
- you type `ls` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- there's not `ls` [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) that would change the command into something else than `ls`;

then Bash will run the first existing `ls` object from the list below. It's [this list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) tailored to your case.

1. `ls` function.
2. `ls` builtin (usually `ls` is not a builtin in Bash; but since Bash can dynamically load new builtin commands, you can make `ls` a builtin).
3. `ls` executable with its full pathname stored in a hash table (this will happen if sometime in the past the `ls` executable was found according to the next point and it's still remembered).
4. `ls` executable from `$PATH`. In your case the sequence is:

   1. `/usr/local/bin/ls`
   2. `/usr/bin/ls`
   3. `/bin/ls`

Note there is no `./ls` in the procedure; nor at any point your current working directory is taken into consideration, especially it's not matched against entries in `$PATH`.

Now this statement

> Linux does not look in the current directory to see whether a specific command is available from that directory

only means there is no `./ls` hardcoded in the above list. It would appear on the list if your `$PATH` contained `.` but

> for security reasons the current directory is not in the `$PATH` variable

I will explain these reasons later in the answer. Still you can add `.` to your `$PATH` on your own. In this case `./ls` would appear on the list as 4.x entry. Compare it to Windows which would look for `ls` in the current working directory *regardless* of whether it's in `$PATH` or not. If Linux did the same, then there would *always* be `./ls` entry hardcoded somewhere above the point 3 of our list.

If your current working directory is `/usr/bin` and the list says `ls` should resolve to `/usr/bin/ls`, then it's technically the same executable than `./ls` but

- the shell never uses the literal `./ls` path, the procedure yields `/usr/bin/ls`;
- the fact you're in `/usr/bin` means *nothing*;
- the fact `/usr/bin` is in `$PATH` means *a lot*.

But if you had `.` as the first entry in your `$PATH` then

- the shell would use the literal `./ls` path;
- the fact you're in `/usr/bin` would mean *a lot*;
- the fact `/usr/bin` is in `$PATH` would mean *nothing*.

In both cases it's the same executable that runs at the end of the day, but the shell gets to it in different ways.

It's also worth noting that statements like "my current working directory is in my `$PATH`" or "I'm in a directory that's in my `$PATH`" don't tell the whole story. They could mean:

- "`/some/particular/directory` is in my `$PATH` and I'm in `/some/particular/directory` at the moment"

or

- "the literal `.` entry is in my `$PATH`".

As shown, the two cases differ.

---

It looks like you expected `ls` not to be found just because you happen to be in its directory. Well, this would be inconvenient while there would be no security advantage whatsoever. The main security reason for not having `.` as a fixed step in a general command search sequence and for not having `.` in `$PATH` are explained in [this UNIX FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html):

> Consider what happens in the case  where `.` is the first entry in the `PATH`. Suppose your current directory is a publically-writable one, such as `/tmp`. If there just happens to be a program named `/tmp/ls` left there by some other user, and you type `ls` (intending, of course, to run the normal `/bin/ls` program), your shell will instead run `./ls`, the other user's program. Needless to say, the results of running an unknown program like this might surprise you.

There is no point of prohibiting `/usr/bin/ls` only because you're in `/usr/bin`. If `ls` there is malicious, you probably have run it already while working in another directory, or you will run it eventually while working in another directory.

---

#### tl;dr

To summarize, `ls` in your example works because it's `/usr/bin/ls` that is found, not `./ls`. The fact that the latter path resolves to the former one doesn't matter because the latter path is not used in the first place. It's not used because "Linux does not look in the current directory…" (meaning it does not look in `.`). It does look in `/usr/bin` nevertheless, because it's in your `$PATH`.